# Disconnected graph for GAN in Keras

Tags: python-2.7, graph, neural-network, keras

For this code:

```
     # Initialize generator - feed noise and profile images
noise = random_normal(shape = (-1, 8, 8, z_dim), mean = 0.0, stddev = 1.0, dtype = None, seed = None)

noise      = Input(tensor = noise)
input_data = Input(shape = (128, 128, 3))

generated_img = generator_network(input_data, noise)

# Initialize discriminator - feed frontal faces as ground truth and the generated images as fake
generated_img = Input(tensor = generated_img)

true_score = discriminator_network(input_data)
fake_score = discriminator_network(generated_img)

# Optimizer
Adam_optimizer = Adam(lr = learning_rate, beta_1 = 0.9, beta_2 = 0.999, epsilon = 1e-08, decay = decay_rate)

# Losses
discrim_loss = discriminator_loss(true_score, fake_score)
var_loss     = variation_loss(input_data, generated_img)
pix_loss     = pixel_loss(input_data, generated_img)
cross_loss   = cross_entropy_loss(true_score, fake_score)
gen_loss     = generator_loss(discrim_loss, var_loss, pix_loss, cross_loss)

# Models
discriminator = Model(inputs = generated_img      , outputs = fake_score)
generator     = Model(inputs = [input_data, noise], outputs = generated_img)

# Compilers
discriminator.compile(optimizer = Adam_optimizer, loss = discriminator_loss)
generator.compile(    optimizer = Adam_optimizer, loss = generator_loss)
```

I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "main.py", line 74, in 
>       generator     = Model(inputs = [input_data, noise], outputs = generated_img)
>     File "/home/diana/Documents/VirtualNN/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 87, in wrapper
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/home/diana/Documents/VirtualNN/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 1793, in **init**
>       str(layers_with_complete_input))
>   RuntimeError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("conv2d_35/Relu:0", shape=(?, ?, ?, 3), dtype=float32) at layer "input_3". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []

Could anyone know why it says that my model generator is not a connected graph? From my understanding, it is connected.
But maybe there is something else I don't see.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the generator network and the discriminator network as two sequential layers within another network if your purpose is to build a GAN model. For example:

```
from keras.models import Sequential

# generator_network() and generator_network() should each have an Input layer 
#   that defines their input shapes respectively
g_network = generator_network()
d_network = discriminator_network()

gan_network = Sequential()
gan_network.add(g_network)
d_network.trainable = False
gan_network.add(d_network)

# Compilers
d_network.compile(optimizer = Adam_optimizer, loss = discriminator_loss)
gan_network.compile(optimizer = Adam_optimizer, loss = generator_loss)
```

Comment: discriminator should be trainable no?